# Django gives error "Select a Valid choice" . Django Version 1.11.5

Tags: python, django, django-models

My models.py is below:

```
from django.db import models
from extensions.models import SipExtension


    xmpp_users = SipExtension.objects.values_list('real_name',flat=True)
    xmpp_users_choices = [('', 'None')] + [(real_name,real_name) for real_name in xmpp_users]

    class xmpp_buddy_groups(models.Model):
        group_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        name = models.CharField(choices=xmpp_users_choices,max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s' % (self.group_name,self.name)
```

my forms.py is below:

```
from django import forms
from .models import xmpp_buddy_groups
from extensions.models import SipExtension

class xmpp_buddy_groups_form(forms.ModelForm):
    xmpp_users = SipExtension.objects.values_list('real_name',flat=True)
    xmpp_users_choices = [('', 'None')] + [(real_name,real_name) for real_name in xmpp_users]
    name = forms.ChoiceField(xmpp_users_choices,required=True, widget=forms.SelectMultiple())
   # name = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,queryset=SipExtension.objects.values_list('real_name',flat=True),required=True)
    class Meta:
      model = xmpp_buddy_groups
      fields = ['group_name']
```

my views.py is below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import xmpp_buddy_groups_form

@login_required
def index(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = xmpp_buddy_groups_form(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/index.html')
            form.save()

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = xmpp_buddy_groups_form()
        print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'xmpp/index.html', {'form': form})
```

My template index.html is below

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create Buddy Groups">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The django gives me invalid choices error. Image is attached. [image]

Thanks to help me. It seems lime the choices for models and choices shown in templates through forms are not matching but I cannot figure out the reason since both are exactly same choices.

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from extensions.models import SipExtension

    class xmpp_buddy_groups(models.Model):
        group_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        name = models.ForiegnKey(SipExtension)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s' % (self.group_name,self.name)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import xmpp_buddy_groups
from extensions.models import SipExtension

class xmpp_buddy_groups_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = xmpp_buddy_groups
      fields = ['group_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(xmpp_buddy_groups_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance:
        self.fields['name'].initial = SipExtension.objects.get(pk=self.instance.SipExtension).real_name
```

Comment: So should I make it textfield? Or what do you suggest?

Comment: do you want multiple names?

Comment: Multiple or single or none. (Any selected option) .